# Report Viewer 14.0 redistributable

Tags: winforms, rdlc, visual-studio-2017

Previous versions of the Microsoft Report Viewer technology for Windows Forms had a [runtime file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496) you could install on a client PC to setup the Microsoft Report Viewer assemblies on the users machine. Does something like this exist for Report Viewer version 14.0 used by Visual Studio 2017? I can't seem to find anything available on the Internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Viewer 14 on VS 2017 is quite nice in that all you need is the nuget package and you have everything you need to run reports. It doesn't require an installation package to run on the target machines.

This makes web applications a lot easier to deploy as you don't have to install anything on the server short of the website itself. And for winforms you just need to include the dll files the nuget package added.

Comment: For those that are having some dificulties to find the package:
I spent some time trying to find it. I was even thinking there was not an official package. When I saw this post, I tried to look further and I've found this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started wich leads to this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms/.

Comment: It does not seem to play well with NServiceBus though. NServiceBus completely refuses to start...

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/07/27/updated-report-viewer-control-now-generally-available/ Nuget packages

Comment: WinForms Version here:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/